# How can I get Location Permission in ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm trying to get Weather infomation by using api.

To use weather api I need Location information.

So I have to use Location Manager.

But in this project I use MVVM design pattern.

So I can't get Location Manager in ViewModel.
And also I can't request permission in viewmodel.

How can I get Location Manager in view model
and how can I use onRequestPermissionsResult() in ViewModel?

And requesting permission in view model and using onRequestPermissionsResult() in ViewModel is right way?

This is my code.

```
public class MAgencyViewModel extends ViewModel{

    private final String TAG = "MAgencyViewModel";

    //이 클래스에서는 Model과 통신하여서 날씨 정보를 받아온다.
    private MutableLiveData<ShortWeather> sw;
    private MAgencyRepo maRepo;

    private LocationManager lm;//핸드폰에 있는 gps관련 기기와 상호작용하기 위해서
    private GpsTransfer gpt;
    private GeoInfo gi;

    //여기서 이제 위치정보를 가지고 날씨정보 API를 호출하는 부분
    public void init(GeoInfo gi){
        if(sw != null){
            return;
        }

        //I want to get Location information in here

        maRepo = MAgencyRepo.getInStance();
        sw = maRepo.getWeather(gi); // this part is calling a weather api
        Log.i(TAG,"API Connection finish");
    }

    public LiveData<ShortWeather> getWeather(){
        return sw;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are asking two questions (go over https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Search StackOverflow about permissions in ViewModel. Regarding the LocationManager, you have two options. Either use Application Context (static or injected), or update your ViewModel (viewMode.updateLocation(...)) whenever your Activity receives a location update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try to make ViewModel as platform independent as possible and especially `Context` free.

So in this case I'd request this on the View layer (Activity, Fragment), since getting the `LocationManager` can be done with [getSystemService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getSystemService(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) which is a function of `Context`. Then delegate the events, such as `onRequestPermissionsResult()` to the `ViewModel`